# set-cookie header safari not saving

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cookies

I can't get safari to save my login cookie, for what I've researched it is because safari doesn't store cross-site cookies. My back-end is on aws, I use API-Gateway. Front-end is stored on AWS S3 with a custom URL.

So back-end and front-end are completely different URL. Is there any way to mantain my architecture but somehow send 'not cross-site' cookies? If the answer is no, that means it is not possible to have a back-end and front-end on different urls and store cookies on safari?.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom domain for my API located on APIGateway (said domain is a subdomain of my front-end URL). Now the cookies are `SameSite: Strict` and Safari is storing them.